# Executing the >> shell operator from a Julia program

Tags: shell, julia

I was trying to append a file from inside Julia using backticks

```
run(`cat file2 >> file1`)
```

but this doesn't work.  It seems the >> operator can't be interpreted correctly.  Is there some way to do this with a pipeline or other trick?

Comment: `>>` is a shell directive. Julia's backticks don't start a shell. This is thus expected behavior.

Comment: @Charles Duffy Can I use >> from inside of Julia?  If I separate it out into `run(pipeline(\`cat file2\`, \`>> file1\`)` it doesn't work either.  (That would probably have been a better example to start with).

Comment: You can use it in the precise manner given in my answer -- within script text passed to an explicit `sh -c` invocation. Otherwise, you'd need to use the pipeline `stdout=` argument to connect output to `file1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will run a string as a literal shell script, circumventing the safeties Julia sets up for you:

```
script = "cat file2 >> file1"
run(`sh -c $script`)
```

Assuming that `file1` and `file2` are parameterized, the following is a safer equivalent (not prone to shell injection attacks, as it passes `file1` and `file2` out-of-band from script text):

```
script = "cat \"\$1\" >> \"\$2\""
source = "file1"
dest = "file2"
run(`sh -c $script _ $source $dest`)
```

This passes `_` as $0, `file1` as `$1`, and `file2` as `$2`.

---

Finally, to avoid a shell altogether, specify `stdout=` to be your file handle:

```
source = "file1"
dest = "file2"
run(pipeline(`cat $source`, stdout=open(dest, "a")))
```

Comment: Very through. I particularly like the pipeline suggestion, but wanted to edit it to make it `run(pipeline(\`cat file2\`, stdout=open("file1","a"))` (which does work) but the system won't let me make such a small change.  Is there some way to do that for a little (obsessive) extra clarity?

Comment: By the way -- I do quite agree with @TasosPapastylianou that if your real goal is to append to a file, rather than to be able to invoke arbitrary shell code from Julia correctly, the better approach is use of native Julia primitives; I'm somewhat blaming myself, right now, for not having read the question as closely for intent.

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear from the main question body if you're trying to do this programmatically *in general*, or just trying to issue a shell command *interactively* from within the julia REPL ... but your title suggests it's the latter; **if** that is the case*, you can drop into *shell mode* by simply typing `;` at the REPL and issuing your shell command.

As for the former case, if you *must* append to a file using the `run` command, then use the built-in `pipeline` mechanism provided for this instead. Read the help file for this and you will see an optional `append` argument can be provided. e.g.

```
run(pipeline(`cat file1`; stdout="file2", append=true));
# or even
run(pipeline(`cat`; stdin="file1", stdout="file2", append=true));
```

Having said that, if you *are* doing this programmatically in general, since all you're doing to file1 is read from it, you should probably just be reading and writing normally to a file instead, and avoid shell-commands altogether:

```
open("file1", "r") do f1; 
  open("file2", "a") do f2; write(f2, readstring(f1)); end
end
```

This is julia-specific, safer, platform independent, *and* more informative.

---

<sub>*: And if that's ***not*** the case, you might want to edit the title of your question :)</sub>

Comment: I'm generally in agreement. That said, with respect to "safer" -- are there any places where my answer is taking inadequate precautions, or is that with respect to previously-unknown bugs (as-yet undiscovered shell bugs akin to shellshock, potential for unknown quoting bugs in Julia, etc)?

Comment: Thanks for your solution as well.  You are correct that the original title was misleading and suggests that I simply wanted to execute a shell command - so I have changed the title.  To fully expand, I had been executing a suite of (compiled C) programs from a Julia script and habitually tried to continue to modify their input and output files through another `run` statement.  Interpreting `>>` was a problem that @CharlesDuffy solved using the interpolation trick.  As a newbie, I didn't think about shell injection attacks and am also interested in any potential bugs/risks.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I didn't have something too specific in mind :) But, what you just said, yes, heheh. I just meant that it's generally safer to use straightforward native functionality for a simple read / write operation, rather than introduce another entry point for bugs / attacks. In any case, I was just covering all bases, since the question seemed general enough to mean any of the above :)   (ultradian, thanks for clarifying!)