# Julia Running External Programs

Tags: unix, julia, pipeline

How would I translate the following into Julia's run/readstring/pipeline() framework?

`home/bin/julia /home/elite_script.jl &>> /home/beckman/elite_log.log &`

Comment: I believe the straightforward answer is "you cannot" (or rather, "you shouldn't do it this way"), since the `pipeline` function requires that at least one of the arguments is a "shell command". If you're not planning to redirect output at the environment level, but you want to do it from within your julia session, then you really should be writing to a file appropriately instead, rather than relying on hacky redirection. Having said that, I'm sure that such a 'hacky' trick exists (presumably redefining the standard STDOUT somehow).

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41010384/executing-the-shell-operator-from-a-julia-program

Comment: what about just running a command in the background with Julia ala `echo make america gay again &`

Comment: See my answer at the 'potential duplicate' link above. If all you're trying to do is execute a shell command from within your REPL session, you can just press `;` and issue your command. Also, if you're trying to perform something asynchronously, you're probably better off using `@async` instead anyway.

Comment: not doing this from the REPL....basically have a script(A) to restart another script(B) which would need to be run in the background as once that script(A) finishes it would cause it's complement(B) to exit/crash if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 4):

This would correspond to:

```
spawn(pipeline(`home/bin/julia /home/elite_script.jl`, stdout="/home/beckman/elite_log.log", append=true))
```

Comment: +1. Alas, this doesn't work as expected (let alone for realtime logging and tracking, which seems to be what OP is after). Check with this script: `i = 0; while true; sleep(1); i += 1; println("$i seconds elapsed"); end`

Comment: It works if you add `flush(STDOUT)` after the println. We seem not to do line buffering; I believe it's this issue: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/13050